# disabling the button and uncheck the checkbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

What I am trying to do is I added two buttons which are disabled by default.when I add an item the buttons will enable once I click receipt button the checkbox checked should go away which is working in my laptop but not in Fiddle and also if I click receipt it should the `removeAttr` checked to the check box and the buttons should disable because no checkbox is checked. Here is my code [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/M8MHc/8).

Javascript:

```
// json data object
var data = JSON.parse('{ "122233334444": ["Book","Three Musketters","DE7598490587","7584092043857", "03/18/13 11:17:51 AM","03/18/13 11:17:51 AM", "1" ], "122223355552":["eBook","Fall Colors","XYZ29494949","7584092043857", "03/18/13 11:17:51 AM","03/18/13 11:17:51 AM", "2" ], "122223355533":["eBook","Snowfall","XYZ29494949","7584092043857", "03/18/13 11:17:51 AM","03/18/13 11:17:51 AM", "3" ] }');
$("#submitid").click(function () {
    $('#resend').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#receipt').removeAttr('disabled');
    var rowId = $("#number").val();
    $("#number").val("");
    var rowData = data[rowId];
    if (rowData) {

        var tr = $("<tr><td><input id='item-id' type='checkbox' checked/></td></tr>").attr("id", "datatable-row-" + rowId);
        for (var col = 0; col < rowData.length; col++)
        tr.append($("<td></td>").text(rowData[col]));
        $("#datatable").prepend(tr);
        $("#datatable").show();
    } else {
        alert("Row doesn't exist in json object: " + rowId);
    }
});
$('#receipt').click(function () {
    $('#item-id').removeAttr('checked');

    $('#resend').attr('disabled');
    $('#receipt').attr('disabled');



});
```

Comment: _cool it is working fine_ -- what is? Seems like context is missing.

Comment: sorry, I am trying to uncheck the checkbox and disable the button at the same time when i click receipt button...

Comment: I was just remarking on how that first sentence sounds like the response to an answer that works, not the start of question.

Comment: you want to uncheck all checkboxes?

Comment: I need to uncheck what ever items are checked and disable the two buttons..when I click receipt button...

Answer (score 0):

First thing, don't use the same id for your checkboxes, **id attributes should be unique in a HTML page**. If you want to uncheck all checkboxes then you can use this:

```
$('#receipt').click(function(){
    $(':checked').removeAttr('checked');
    $('#resend, #receipt').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M8MHc/11/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple elements with the same ID, IDs have to be unique. Instead of `id="item-id"` you should use a class, `class="item-id"`.

And to remove the checkmark, you should use `removeProp('checked')`, not `removeAttr('checked')`. Attributes refer to static DOM attributes, which are used only as the initial setting of input elements, properties are the dynamic changes that a user can make to the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing different behavior in different browsers because you are using duplicate HTML element ids (they should be unique!) and jQuery `.attr()` and `.removeAttr()` where you should be using [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/). This will ensure that your code will work more reliably in different browsers.

Remove the duplicate ids. The new code won't reference them anymore.

To uncheck all checked checkboxes you can use a simple selector, such as

```
$('#datatable :checkbox')
```

or

```
$('#datatable :checkbox:checked')
```

Changes to the JS code (**[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M8MHc/15/)**)

```
$("#submitid").click(function () {
    $('#resend').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#receipt').prop('disabled', false);
```

and

```
$('#receipt').click(function(){
    $('#datatable :checkbox:checked').prop('checked', false);
    $('#resend').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#receipt').prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#receipt').on("click",function(){
    $(':checked').removeAttr('checked');

    $('#resend').attr('disabled','disabled');
    $('#receipt').attr('disabled','disabled');



});
```

[**FIDDLE Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/M8MHc/13/)